# Why my 'for' loop function doesn't work in sass?

Tags: angular, sass

I am trying to call @for loop in my style file but it doesn't work.
here is what I tried

```
@for $i from 1 to 50{
.point-#{i}{
  background-color: red;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-animation: movee 5s infinite;
  animation: movee 10s infinite;
  margin-left: #{i};
  margin-top: #{i} + 1;
}
  @keyframes movee {
    0% {
      margin-left: 0px;
    }
    50% {
      margin-left: 200px;
    }
    100% {
      margin-left: 0px;
    }
  }

}
```

> and nothing styles are shown on my points class.
>
> > in HTML I wrote with typescript like this

```
  ngOnInit() {
    for (let i = 1; i <= 50; i++) {
      this.point += '<div class="point-' + i + '"></div>';
    }
  }
```

> here is my template

```
<div class="move" [innerHtml]="point">
</div>
```

Comment: show the html code.

Comment: I edited my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use `#{$i}` instead of `#{i}` for the class name accessor in your sass code and `$i` for values.
You can see some examples here: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/interpolation

I also found a good example here:
http://thesassway.com/intermediate/if-for-each-while